# Getting com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: SQL syntax

Tags: java, mysql, sql

```
do 
{ 
String mid=res.getString(1); 
String model=res.getString(2); 
String name=res.getString(3); 
int price=res.getInt(4); 
String pcolor=res.getString(5); 
String imei=res.getString(6); 
java.sql.Date date=res.getDate(7);
String access=res.getString(8); 

if(id.equals(mid) || id.equals(imei)) 
{ 
System.out.println("iam inside"); 
PreparedStatement prp=con2.prepareStatement("insert into msearch values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"); 
prp.setString(1,mid); 
prp.setString(2,model); 
prp.setString(3,name); 
prp.setInt(4,price); 
prp.setString(5,pcolor); 
prp.setString(6,imei); 
prp.setDate(7,date); 
prp.setString(8,access); 

prp.executeUpdate(); 

System.out.println("iam inside2"); 
rows++; 
b=1; 
jTextField1.setText(""); 
} 

}while(res.next());
```

I am new to mysql

I am trying to execute above code ,I got

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an
>   error in your SQL  syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax  to use near '' at line 1

what should be the problem,please help,

Comment: you're doing an executeUpdate, shouldn't there be an equivalent for executeQuery / executeInsert?

Comment: @BryanMoyles No `ExecuteInsert`.

Comment: As an aside, you really should specify the column names in your INSERTs (i.e. `insert into table (c1, c2, ...) values (...)`), don't depend on the columns ever being in any particular order.

Answer (score 0):

Change your prepareStatement like this;

```
     insert into msearch (mid, model, name, price, pcolor, imei, date, access) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
```